# Implementing MouseMotionListener in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

Continuing on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848552/combining-mouselisteners-with-polygons-in-graphics2d/32849494#32849494), I'm implementing a `MouseMotionListener` in my `JPanel` so that I can track mouse events to pass down to the objects contained within.

This didn't work, so I implemented a completely clean `JPanel` (that has none of the other stuff my game panel has) with a `MouseMotionListener` and that still didn't work. It's just set up in a very simple `JFrame` with a `FlowLayout`.

Am I using it wrong? How am I meant to trigger the mouse events?

`JPanelMouseMotion` class:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JPanelMouseMotion extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JPanelMouseMotion() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getX() + " / " + e.getY());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listener is never called because it is never registered. You should call [`addMouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseMotionListener-java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener-) to register it.

```
public class JPanelMouseMotion extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JPanelMouseMotion() {
        super();
        addMouseMotionListener(this); // register this JPanel as a Listener
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getX() + " / " + e.getY());
    }

}
```